# Using Twig variable inside Twig variable

Tags: php, twig

I have a language JSON file containing the text of each page on my website. So to fetch the title of the page, I'll do something like

```
{{ translation.page1.title }}
```

In order to fetch the title for page 1.

I already have a page variable that tells me the name of the page, I was wondering if it was possible to do something to avoid having a giant if statement for each page such as:

```
{{ translation.{{ page }}.title }}
```

I've looked through the twig doc and I have no idea.

Comment: `{{ translation[page].title }}` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your variable between brackets

```
{{ translation[page].title }}
```

That should be work